# GoodData attributes with multiple tags

Tags: gooddata

We do not have a current example of what the value would look like for attributes with multiple tags.  So for attributes that have multiple tags, how are the tags separated in the meta.tags property?

Answer (score 1):

In GoodData the tags are actually separaye by a space. So multiple tags are multiple words separated by a space and the whole meta.tags is actually not an array but a string.